# Flutter - Get icon from name;

Tags: flutter, dart

In the backend, icons are setup using text like `"fas fa-camera"`. I can split and extract the name `"camera"` from the icon name. How do I get the FontAwesomeIcon of the same name from the font_awesome_flutter package?

```dart
class FontAwesomeIcons{
  static const IconData camera = const IconDataBrands(0xf26e);
}
```

I can hardcode a list of all icon data and compare but that's my last resort right now. Is there anything I can do without doing that?

Answer (score 0):

As in package description:

Icon names equal those on the official website, but are written in lower camel case. If more than one icon style is available for an icon, the style name is used as prefix, except for "regular".

Comment: That is the conventions of the icon name. What I need is the way to get that specific `IconData` from the name. If I have a string `camera`, I need to get `FontAwesomeIcons.camera` IconData which I cannot get from the name string at this moment.